# Implement SSO with PHP for automatic user login with multiple domains

Tags: php, single-sign-on

I need to implement a Single Sing On system for three websites, I have been looking into it and googleing and after some research I'm a little stuck and confused :)I have found to much information, but non of them make the things completely clear for me, so I decide to ask you experts to see if you can point me in the right direction.

I have been reading about OpenSSO, OpenAM, CAS and other solution, but didn't help me as I expected, at least so far.

The scenario is as follows:

I have three websites developed with PHP and MySQL, the three sites share the same database and the same users, but every site is in its own domain so the users have to log in three ties if they want to access the three websites.

What I would like to achieve is give the user the ability to log in on one of the sites and after be able to automatically be logged on the other two as they access the site.

Technically speaking I would like to have the less possible impact on my already production/working code.

What is the best solution can I use?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be easier if the user who firstly visits **site A** will visit **site B** or **C** through a link you made for them in **site A**, that is to say, if they click a link in one of theirs sites to go to another, then you could just use **url-based sessions** and in **PHP** use the **database backend** for sessions.

Comment: thanks @Nelson, i need to give the user the ability to be logged in even if they just type the URL but the url based auth is nice for the links in my own site :)